# VueJS application doesn't load on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, cross-browser, babeljs

I keep getting this error on IE:

> SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier bundle.js

I found a solution in a form of a module called [targets-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/targets-webpack-plugin) which works like a charm but also created a new issue on my app. Whenever I try debugging on Google Chrome via sourcemaps, instead of displaying the source of the file containing the error, it displays like this:

> ReferenceError: parents is not defined
>       at deserializeParent (bundle.js:16180)
>       at bundle.js:16192

The sourcemaps seemed not to function as it should. This would be the expected output:

> ReferenceError: parents is not defined
>       at deserializeParent (account.ts:44)
>       at account.ts:117

Now removing the targets-webpack-plugin would bring me back to the same issue of not running my app on IE. Here are my webpack configurations:

```
module.exports = {
  context: path.dirname(__dirname),
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js',
  },
  target: 'web',

  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    hashDigestLength: 8,
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    },
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  stats: 'errors-only',

  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      tslint: true,
      reportFiles: ['src/**/*.ts'],
    }),
    new StylishWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      USE_LOGROCKET: withLogRocket,
    }),
    // new TargetsPlugin({
    //   browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'chrome >= 41', 'not ie <= 8', '> 1%'],
    // }),
  ],
};
```

Above is the base webpack configuration while here is my dev webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = merge(baseConfig, {
  mode: 'development',

  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'https://localhost:8080/',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 4096,
              name: 'img/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

And lastly here is my .babelrc file:

```
{
    "presets": ["env"],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-es2015-destructuring",
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

I tried [this](https://makandracards.com/makandra/52051-webpacker-configuring-browser-compatibility) and [this](http://superdavid.me/ie/front-end/2018/01/17/expected-identifier-error.html) to no avail. I tried changing my babelrc file from the suggestion on the aforementioned link yet since it did not work I had to revert. I also tried es3ify but I seem to get **spread must be the final element of an element list** when compiling my code. I also tried using **babel-polyfill** but no cigar so I had to revert back to my original webpack configuration. I also already have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` on my index.html file yet it didn't seem to help me either. Is there a way that I can solve the IE issue while not breaking sourcemaps (on Chrome) at the same time? Any node module or some changes on the configuration that can help me?

EDIT: I also tried babel-preset-env but didn't work either.

EDIT: Tested on IE 11

Comment: What IE version are you having problems with? They vary a lot.

Comment: 11 and below (not below 7 though). The important version we would want to have a coverage of is from 8 above. We have no issues on MS Edge..

Comment: No version below IE11 supports source maps at all. IE11 and Edge do but they're apparently somewhat tempermental.

Comment: But actually the issue on sourcemaps reflect on Chrome and Firefox, we need these on debugging our apps. :) Wait let me edit the question.. The issue on sourcemaps pertain to Chrome, on one end we have sourcemaps working on Chrome and the app doesn't run on IE, and on the other we have an app working on IE yet sourcemaps is not functioning on Chrome.. I hope this makes sense. :)